# Recovering from lengthy rom upgrade on HTC Desire S

Tags: updates, rom, htc

I started installing Android 4.0.4 on HTC Desire S from the official website. It had an executable that I just launched and clicked through to start installation. It should have taken about ten minutes but now it is over half an hour later. There's no progress bar on the phone. I can only see "Sending.." (with number of dots growing repeatedly) on my laptop (under Windows 7). Is there a way to recover from this situation? Is my phone doomed to be bricked if I just disconnect usb?

Answer (score 0):

I disconnected the usb and then some sort of debug screen showed up and gave me an option to reboot the phone. To my astonishment I still had Android 2.3.5 installed and working. It looks like installation of new ROM newer really took off. 
The second attempt to upgrading rom succeceded.